# Reduce using the lowest value

Tags: code-golf, number

**The challenge**

Create a function which takes an array of numbers and subtract from each element the lowest element in the array that has not yet been subtracted from another.

- After using the lowest value, It can not be used again.
- Numbers in the array are decimal numbers, and not necessarily integers.

**Example:**

```
Input: [6, 4, 7, 8, 9, 2, 1, 4]

Next lowest value:          Output:
[6, 4, 7, 8, 9, 2, 1, 4]    [6, 4, 7, 8, 9, 2, 1, 4]
                   ^         ^
                            6-1 = 5
[6, 4, 7, 8, 9, 2, -, 4]    [5, 4, 7, 8, 9, 2, 1, 4]
                ^               ^
                            4-2 = 2
[6, 4, 7, 8, 9, -, -, 4]    [5, 2, 7, 8, 9, 2, 1, 4]
    ^                              ^
                            7-4 = 3
[6, -, 7, 8, 9, -, -, 4]    [5, 2, 3, 8, 9, 2, 1, 4]
                      ^               ^
                            8-4 = 4
[6, -, 7, 8, 9, -, -, -]    [5, 2, 3, 4, 9, 2, 1, 4]
 ^                                       ^
                            9-6 = 3
[-, -, 7, 8, 9, -, -, -]    [5, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2, 1, 4]
       ^                                    ^
                            2-7 = -5
[-, -, -, 8, 9, -, -, -]    [5, 2, 3, 4, 3,-5, 1, 4]
          ^                                    ^
                            1-8 = -7
[-, -, -, -, 9, -, -, -]    [5, 2, 3, 4, 3,-5,-7, 4]
             ^                                    ^
                            4-9 = -5

Final output: [5, 2, 3, 4, 3, -5, -7, -5]
```

**Test Cases**

`Input: [6, 4, 7, 8, 9, 2, 1, 4] => Output: [5, 2, 3, 4, 3, -5, -7, -5]`

`Input: [4, 7, 4, 9, -10, 8, 40] => Output: [14, 3, 0, 2, -18, -1, 0]`

`Input: [0.25, -0.5, 8, 9, -10] => Output: [10.25, 0, 7.75, 1, -19]`

`Input: [3, 4, 9, 1, 1, 1, -5] => Output: [8, 3, 8, 0, -2, -3, -14]`

---

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest answer in bytes win.

Comment: This could use an walk-through example. As it stands now the task needs to be inferred from the test cases.

Comment: Thanks @Arnauld for taking the time to do it. I haven't been able to use the pc since yesterday so I couldn't modify the example

Comment: Is there a specific reason to include non-integers in the arrays? It doesn't make the challenge more interesting, rules out some approaches, and poses a big problem in languages without non-integer types.

Answer (score 15):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 2 bytes

```
_Ṣ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z/@4c5F////jzbTUTDRUTDXUbDQUbDUUTDSUTAEisQCAA)

or [Try all test cases](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z/@4c5F/w@3P2pa4w3Ekf//R0eb6SiY6CiY6yhY6ChY6igY6SgYAkVidbiiIcImYGFdQwOwChMDkIyBnpEpUMxAzxSmDSgPkjCGqTeEIV3T2FgA)

```
_   # Subtract from...
 Ṣ  # The input array sorted
```

Answer (score 5):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 3 bytes

```
tS-
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/vyRY9///aDMdBRMdBXMdBQsdBUsdBSMdBUOgSCwA)

```
(implicit input as an array)
t                              # duplicate
 S                             # sort
  -                            # element-wise subtract
(implicit output)
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 4 bytes

```
Ṡz-O
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//@HOBVW6/v///4820THXMdGx1NE1NNCx0DExiAUA)

**Explanation**

```
      -- input, e.g. [6,4,7,8,9,2,1,4]
   O  -- sort        [1,2,4,4,6,7,8,9]
Ṡz-   -- element wise difference to input: [6-1,4-2,7-4,8-4,9-6,2-7,1-8,4-9]
      -- return result [5,2,3,4,3,-5,-7,-5]
```

Comment: This have to be a joke..... 4 bytes. Awesome

Answer (score 4):

## [Prolog (SWI)](http://www.swi-prolog.org), <s>93</s> <s>80</s> 68 bytes

```
[H|T]/[A|B]/[X|Y]:-X is H-A,(T=[],Y=T;T/B/Y).
X*Y:-msort(X,S),X/S/Y.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KyjKz8lP1y0uz/z/P9qjJiRWP9qxxglIRtRExlrpRihkFit46DrqaITYRsfqRNqGWIfoO@lHaupxRWhFWunmFucXlWhE6ARr6kToB@tH6gFNMdAzMtVR0DXQA5IWOgqWQLahQaxWhB4A)

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (ES6), 44 bytes

```javascript
a=>[...a].map(x=>x-a.sort((a,b)=>b-a).pop())
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Zc9LDoMgEAbgfU/BEhJmBB9VF3oR4wKtNm2sGDWNt7cwxk1NCGQG@Ph5m69Z2vk1rTDaR7f3xW6KskJEU@PHTHwryg0MLnZeOTeyEUXZgBE42YkLsbd2XOzQ4WCfvOfVXbJYslSyTLJcslAy7Tq1ECwIWJVQJ6IzbgZXQ@rX@vbnHEhMCGhFXqxORx/3FXGgMz@58qIoDP0TCpMzkLM8cijHtlNSTBNKCjq/INGZQ5/D5fUGIRklyYgBn8b/S8f1/gM)

#### Commented

```javascript
a =>                 // given the input array a[]
  [...a]             // create a copy of a[]
  .map(x =>          // for each integer x in the copy:
    x -              //   update x by ...
    a.sort((a, b) => //     sorting the original array in descending order
      b - a          //     (we only need to sort it once, but it's shorter to do it here)
    ).pop()          //     taking the element at the top of a[] and subtracting it from x
  )                  // end of map()
```

Answer (score 3):

## Python 3, <s>42</s> 40 bytes

<s>`lambda a:[b-c for b,c in zip(a,sorted(a))]`</s>

```
lambda a:[a.pop(0)-b for b in sorted(a)]
```

Comment: [37 bytes](https://tio.run/##DclLCoAgEADQq8xSYQiK6AedpGIYMSnID2qLTm9u3wtfvrzriln38rBVmoEXy0HcLjdE6VVEyJh8zKcWLGUJsRYYsQ0IPcKIMCHMCB1CW@WQ5Qc) using `map`.

Comment: @ovs Your solution sort of works for Python 3. It returns a `map` object, instead of a list. Would that be kind of a grey area for the requirements of the contest? Maybe you could just submit it as your own answer, since it's probably different enough to qualify.

Comment: @ovs The spec also states that the input will not necessarily be `int`s, so I'm going to leave mine as is.

Comment: Returning a `map` object is valid, but the non-int requirement makes my suggestion invalid.

Answer (score 3):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), <s>8</s> <s>6</s> 4 bytes

```
í-Uñ
```

[Try it here](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=7S1V8Q&input=WzAuMjUsIC0wLjUsIDgsIDksIC0xMF0)

---

### Explanation

```
           :Implicit input of array U
c          :Flatten (simply creates a 2nd copy of the array because JavaScript's sort mutates the original array)
  í        :Interleave
    Un     :U sorted
   -       :Reduce each pair by subtraction
```

Answer (score 3):

## Ruby, 32 chars

```
->a{a.zip(a.sort).map{|x,y|x-y}}
```

Comment: You could just print the values: ->a{a.zip(a.sort){|x,y|p x-y}}

Answer (score 3):

## Java 10, 83 bytes

```java
a->{var b=a.clone();java.util.Arrays.sort(b);for(int i=0;i<a.length;a[i]-=b[i++]);}
```

Modifies the input-array instead of returning a new one to save bytes.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##dZBfa8IwFMXf/RT3McU2VKf7Q9bBPsB88VF8uG2ji4uJJNcOkX72LqYWBiqEQC7n5Hfu2WGD2a7@6SqN3sMXKnMeAShD0m2wkrC4PAEaq2qoWG2PpZarNWAiwrwdhcsTkqpgAQYK6DD7ODfooCyQV9oayRKxCxB@JKX5p3N48txbR6xMxMY6FlCgilyod@Rami19C1ypdVaUKzUerxPRduKCOQRywFxpMc8@pGVLcspsY6Q@KklPzMhfGMKen1OYpfCSwmsKbylMU5iESRtXuKfvxbMoziZ59M3yx/qcT@dBmfP5gAiux/Kn4e/JcLJ5e9Nn3DCa/5Xeb2h4xfD6/fLkSe65PRI/hCJIG3ZTN9m@pGC6YtruDw)

**Explanation:**

```java
a->{                         // Method with double-array parameter and no return-type
  var b=a.clone();           //  Create a copy of the input-array
  java.util.Arrays.sort(b);  //  Sort this copy
  for(int i=0;i<a.length;    //  Loop over the indices
    a[i]-=                   //   Subtract from the `i`'th item in the input-array:
          b[i++]);}          //    The `i`'th item of the sorted array
```

Answer (score 3):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 18 bytes

```r
(x=scan())-sort(x)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/X6PCtjg5MU9DU1O3OL@oRKNC87@ZgomCuYKFgqWCkYKhgsl/AA)

Does what it says :)

Answer (score 3):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 34 bytes

```hs
import Data.List
zipWith(-)<*>sort
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7NyfmfmVuQX1Si4JJYkqjnk1lcwpVmG/O/KrMgPLMkQ0NX00bLrhgo/z83MTNPwVahoCgzr0RBRSFNIdpMR8FER8FcR8FCR8FSR8FIR8EQKBL7/19yWk5ievF/3eSCAgA)

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 2 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
{-
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f@/Wvf//2gzHRMdcx0LHUsdIx1DHZNYAA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/X9u66GVh9b9r9b9H3to9//oaDMdEx1zHQsdSx0jHUMdk1gdhWiQgAlQQNfQAChhYgASM9AzMtXRNdAzBSsFyoAEjcHKDMFQ1zQ2FgA).

**Explanation:**

```
{     # Sort the input-array
 -    # Subtract all values in this sorted array from the input-array
```

Answer (score 2):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 4 bytes

```
-/:~
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NctBCsIwEEbhfU7xcBMEnU5qUttAz5JFMRQ3LrrWq6cxEGb3vX/eJR@roES03If4K1dzEWxexXLjG8mHMa9t/5CZ8DyZWRhx@M5/9BWT0xq9dlcZA0kltJdae3i0uWuXQjkB)

### Explanation:

From the argument subtract `-` the sorted `/:~` argument

Answer (score 2):

## Common Lisp, 46 bytes

```
(lambda(x)(mapcar #'- x(sort(copy-seq x)#'<)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Fcg7DoAgEAXAq7yEgt2CQkP8JF5mRQsSEAQLPD3GKccFX3OnXPz1gDoFifsh1JiiZCcFShs0qqk85FJ@TT1vNFZ6Y@auaYLFjAUrRgywf34)

Answer (score 2):

## [Coconut](http://coconut-lang.org/), 23 bytes

```
a->map((-),a,sorted(a))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY7LDoMgEEX3fsUsuoBkIGChj4X@iHVBLCYmVYzgrv9OEUOT2cw5dzJ3cINb9hDH5hUNa2ezEsIoGvRuC/ZNDKUxWB88NNDdEBTCHeGB8ESoEWQiPUJ3YpUxkyInlDiM4LVOTHBdzpI/xLXkZRmm@6o6n31bSFUu5DP5AJzDSP9o3aYl5DU19/ts4w8)

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 15 bytes

```perl6
{@^a Z-@a.sort}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJKmYPu/2iEuUSFK1yFRrzi/qKT2f3EiSEIj2kxHwURHwVxHwUJHwVJHwUhHwRAoEqtpzQVTAZE2AUvrGhqAVZoYxGr@BwA)

Anonymous function that takes one list and returns a list.

Answer (score 2):

## [Julia 0.6](http://julialang.org/), 12 bytes

```julia
A->A-sort(A)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY1BCsMgFET3nmKWCXyDJpq0ixY8h7gopAVDMOU3Pb8VizCrN2@Y7bvHx5z5lp28O/k5@Oxcn18HwyEmeD8TDGEhXAhXwkjQZAJB@D82FUutqmFUrdQw2gLVYNuuCLWZ2kK3SBsCxJtjOvfUcbnvxTOt@Qc)

Answer (score 2):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://codeberg.org/ngn/k), 8 bytes

```
{x-x@<x}
```

[Try it online!](https://ngn.codeberg.page/k#eJxLs6qu0K1wsKmo5eJKt0pzSMiy50pXijbTUTDRUTDXUbDQUbDUUTDSUTAEisQqgeQgEiZgCV1DA7AaEwOInIGekSlQ1EDPFKYVqAIiZQzTYwhDuqaxSgAxlxpa)

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 9 bytes

```
íNc n
®r-
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osKPn///Bav2SFPK5D64p0//@PNtNRMNFRMNdRsNBRsNRRMNJRMASKxAIA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 5 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
ÿ◙┘¿N
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=980ad9a84e&i=[6,+4,+7,+8,+9,+2,+1,+4]%0A[4,+7,+4,+9,+-10,+8,+40]%0A[0.25,+-0.5,+8,+9,+-10]+%0A[3,+4,+9,+1,+1,+1,+-5]&a=1&m=2)

To show how it works, here's the unpacked, commented version.

```
m       for each element execute, then pop and print:
  xo    sort the original input
  i@    index into array using iteration index
  -     subtract
```

[Run this one](https://staxlang.xyz/#c=m+++%09for+each+element+execute,+then+pop+and+print%3A%0A++xo%09sort+the+original+input%0A++i%40%09index+into+array+using+iteration+index%0A++-+%09subtract&i=[6,+4,+7,+8,+9,+2,+1,+4]%0A[4,+7,+4,+9,+-10,+8,+40]%0A[0.25,+-0.5,+8,+9,+-10]+%0A[3,+4,+9,+1,+1,+1,+-5]&a=1&m=2)

Comment: [another 5](https://staxlang.xyz/#c=co%5CmE-&i=[6,+4,+7,+8,+9,+2,+1,+4]%0A[4,+7,+4,+9,+-10,+8,+40]%0A[0.25,+-0.5,+8,+9,+-10]+%0A[3,+4,+9,+1,+1,+1,+-5]&a=1&m=2)

Answer (score 1):

## SmileBASIC, 49 bytes

```
DEF R A
DIM B[0]COPY B,A
SORT B
ARYOP 1,A,A,B
END
```

The input array is modified in place.

`ARYOP` does operations on entire arrays at once. In this case it subtracts `B` from `A` and stores the result in `A`.

Answer (score 0):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 86 bytes

```php
function f($a){$b=$a;sort($b);return array_map(function($x,$y){return $y-$x;},$b,$a);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hc3dCoJAEAXg@55ikAF3YRQ17YetfJCKWMtQSF02BUV8dlssoYsgGOZiON8clalxFyuz7015rfOqhDtDyXtM9ijFs9I1w4QLndaNLkFqLbtLIRWb4wxbwo73nwB2DrZiIEzIfBHDmF6zCvJCPapbymyyyfw/rghCgjXBhmBLEBD45nLmHFywTqUlFj/Z24STcXxv4qH3l3luEBngudFcaPBftZyb/Hmc6BvFh/EF)

Answer (score 0):

## [Tcl](http://tcl.tk/), 49 bytes

```
proc S L {lmap n $L m [lsort -r $L] {expr $n-$m}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HY07CsMwEER7nWIwbmUkR8rvDO5cmhTBpJNsISsQWPbsylpss/PmwZQ11JryvmLGBArxnbChnxCxhGPPBTpLfIE@vyTfpvvIXJsnvqIrHG6444ERFo4VndlJ1tYId0aQGUYPbQbfRCmEXZpk22nPikHpWw50Mv7EMp@rHdc/)

Answer (score 0):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org), 23 bytes

```factor
[ dup natural-sort v- ]
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=PY4xDoJAEEV7T_EvsAQQFPUAxsbGWBmLDS5KhAWXWRJDOInNNngFz-JtXECdKebnvfxkHs-Ex1Qo8zb73Wa7XuIqlBQZck4Xpxa9q1AqQXQvVSoJlbhpIWNRoSoUpfKM1aSZwE6DGQLMEWEBH57N7Zf3NLCUea61gfsXruOHYK4TDqVe_8x0KHjDstDittOUsOh1wEmXkJy04hnrf0DNcBxtl_MSzpiNGe8H)